# How to catch an error being thrown in my useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

In this program, the user can upload a profile pic that is saved to a server and it is saved in local storage. I save it in local storage so that the user doesn't always have to download the image when they switch tabs. For example, if they go from home tab to profile tab, to home tab to profile tab again they will have downloaded the same image twice, which is every time they visit the profile tab.

I kind of solved this by saving the image to local storage after the first time they download the image. Now if they did the above scenario again, it would only download the image once and then grab it from local storage every time after that until they closed the website. My issue is that, I can't figure out the logic on how to check if an image is stored locally first and if not, then download the image from the server and save it to local storage.

I tried doing the below but it keeps throwing an error even though theres a catch block. This try catch is in a useEffect() hook.

```
        try{
          setProfilePic(localStorage.getItem('image'));
        } catch(e) {
          downloadProfilePic();
        }
```

I also tried by checking if the localStorage wasn't null, then I'd use the image in local storage. However, when the user refreshes the page, the value of the blob changes and doesn't load the image correctly. Here's the code for that

```
        if(localStorage.getItem('image') !== null){
          setProfilePic(localStorage.getItem('image'));
        }
        else{
          downloadProfilePic();
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, don't try to optimize this with JavaScript. Instead, let the *browser* handle it - browsers are very good at handling and optimizing these sorts of duplicate requests.

First make sure your server has a reasonable cache policy - for example, ensure that images served have headers that keep in in the cache for a while. Then, all you need to do is render the same image link, and that image will be downloaded *exactly once*, until the cache expires.

If the user gets to a page with their image on one tab, then opens up another tab to a similar page with another link to the image, the browser will not re-download the image - instead, it'll render the already-downloaded image in its cache.

So, all you really need is something like

```
<img src={profilePicSrc} />
```

and to make sure `profilePicSrc` is not different across pageloads/tabs (unless the user causes a change by changing their profile pic).

Comment: How do I go about doing what you talked about in your second paragraph. I'm using firebase storage and it's native methods. So no express or stuff like that. 

This is how I upload the images to the server in case it'll help 
```
     firebase.storage().ref('users/'+ user.uid + '/profile.jpg').put(image).then( () => {
        console.log("Successfully uploaded image")
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Error uploading image: " + error);
      });
```

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache It says *Any requested static content is automatically cached on the CDN* so you may not have to do anything at all. *Most* pages have decent caching policies by default anyway, so it's not surprising if it's already implemented properly.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to research more about it right now, thanks again!

Comment: Hey, I just realized something. I think I'm not actually downloading the image like I previously thought. I'm using this method to get the imageURL and then setting the profile pic to it. I just want to make sure I'm correct and I'm not actually downloading the image.

firebase.storage().ref('users/'+ user.uid + '/profile.jpg').getDownloadURL()

Comment: Yes, 99% of the time, you'll be downloading and rendering a *link*, not an actual Image blob. `getDownloadURL` sounds like it gives you the link, not the blob.